# Android: How to display message when call is received and ended?

Tags: android, telephony

i am applying the following code to display message for three state,

1) call rejected
2) call received
3) call ended

```
     TelephonyManager telephonyManager;

     PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener() {

public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber) {

switch (state) {

case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:


Toast.makeText(c, "Call Ended..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.i("stop", "Call Ended....");

        break;

case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:

     Toast.makeText(c, "Call Picked..",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.i("received", "Call Picked....");


        break;

case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:

     Toast.makeText(c, "Call Ringing.." + phonenumber,
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
    }

    }

    };
// Register the listener with the telephony manager
telephonyManager.listen(listener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        }
```

when i am rejecting call , then also it goes in hook_state, how to display message for two separate received and call declined/rejected

Thanks in advance..

Please help

Answer (score 0):

i think you must have already solved this...
but for someone else who has similar issue.

Phone doesn't go in `OFFHOOK` state if you reject the call.

it first goes in 'RINGING' state for incoming call and then `IDLE` state.

For outgoing call, it goes in `OFFHOOK` state and then `IDLE` state.